# Android Firebase: Filter with equalTo and order by a different child at the same time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have posts by users and I want to get all posts of one user in the right order (by the time posted).

So I need something like this:

```
Query query = reference
                .child("Posts")
                .orderByChild("user_id")
                .equalTo(given_user_id)
                .orderByChild("negative_timestamp");
```

---

But that doesn't work because Firebase only allows one `orderByChild()` call in a Query.

How to solve this?

Comment: You can use the ascending and descending direction variable to retrieve posts in any direction you need.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For example, you could create `"user_id-negative_timestamp": "given_user_id-timestamp_value"`, and then filter with `startAt` and `endBefore`. For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This helps!! I only have the problem now that I don't use `endAt()` correctly I think. Because it returns 0 posts now. I used this: `query.orderByChild("userid_negativetimestamp").startAt(given_user_id).endAt(given_user_id)`

The `startAt()` seems to not cause the problem. It seems that I use `endAt` the wrong way

Comment: The child `userid_negativetimestamp` looks like this: The user ID and then just appended (without space or something) the current timestamp with a leading minus

Comment: I now solved it by this: `.endAt(given_user_id + "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")` But I dont think this is a good solution xD Is it?